# Spring Cloud Stream + Kafka Binder: What is the default partition key extractor strategy or partition key?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, partitioning, spring-cloud-stream

I'm looking to implement a scenario where consumer order does not matter, and want to publish to multiple partitions.

In this scenario, what would the strategy be used to select a partition if partition-key-expression is not specified in the producer definition? i.e with this config I see the messages being published to all 4 topics, but it is not clear what mechanism is being used:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        outbound:
          destination: mytopic
          group: app
          producer:
            partitioned: true
            partition-count: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binder level partitioning is really not needed with the Kafka binder; it is intended for binders where the underlying technology does not have native partitioning.

There is no need to set the `partitioned=true` property.

Kafka's default strategy is used

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_partitioner.class

If there is no `partitioner.class` specified...

> If not set, the default partitioning logic is used. This strategy will try sticking to a partition until batch.size bytes is produced to the partition.

> It works with the strategy:

> If no partition is specified but a key is present, choose a partition based on a hash of the key

> If no partition or key is present, choose the sticky partition that changes when batch.size bytes are produced to the partition.

Comment: gotcha - ty! also found it under the heading "Some caveats to keep in mind" in this article https://spring.io/blog/2021/02/03/demystifying-spring-cloud-stream-producers-with-apache-kafka-partitions

Comment: missed it on that first read through